# How to import Rhythmbox podcasts into Banshee?

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox, podcast

With Natty, the default music-player changed from Rhythmbox to Banshee. While my music seems to have moved along, the podcasts didn't. I have therefore two questions :

- How can I listen the podcasts I downloaded with Rhythmbox from Banshee ?
- How can I ask Banshee to automatically download the podcasts Rhythmbox was downloading for me?

**Edited to add** a clarification : I'm interested in a way to subscribe to all the podcasts I was subscribed to in Rhythmbox. I'm asking this question because I'd prefer not to subscribe to the podcasts one by one.

Comment: I'm interested to this question also, especially that I subscribed to some video podcast which are rather big and would not want to re-download again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to get the old podcasts out, but adding the podcasts and re-syncing can be done as shown below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes I know how to add podcast one by one, but it can be long. I'm asking for a way to subscribe all podcasts at once.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a workaround then an answer. You can get a list of podcast that you are subscribed in Rhythmbox with:

```
apt-get install xgrep
xgrep -x '/rhythmdb/entry[@type="podcast-feed"]/location/text()' ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml | grep ^http | sort
```

You can get a list of podcasts you are subscribed to in Banshee with:

```
apt-get install sqlite3
echo "select Url from PodcastSyndications;" | sqlite3  -batch ~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db | sort
```

This doesn't help you import them, as Banshee seems to have no way to add multiple Podcasts in one go, but at least it helps making sure that all Podcasts made it over when you manually added them.

One could probably write some SQL to insert the podcast list into Banshees config files, but I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this but found no precise solution.

However, given that there does not appear to be a way to do exactly what you desire, the following command-line script from [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5662/creates-podfeeds.txt-a-file-that-lists-the-urls-of-rhythmbox-podcasts-from-the-rhythmdb.xml-file.) may be the best thing available to you:

```
grep -A 5 -e podcast-feed rhythmdb.xml | grep -e "<location>" | sed 's: *</*[a-t]*>::g' > PodFeeds.txt
```

This outputs a new-line separated txt list of all the feed URLs that you are subscribed to in Rhythmbox. These may then be easily copied and pasted into whatever podcast player you want to use.